# ¿Como puedo resolver este problema "Error Code: 1109. Unknown table 'idalumno' in MULTI DELETE"?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, delete

Quiero eliminar múltiples datos datos por medio de un tabla nombrada **Bajas**, de la tabla **alumno**. Trate con esta pero me pone el Error 1109. Aqui esta la query que use.

```
DELETE a.idAlumno 
FROM registrobiblioteca.alumno a 
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT Matricula B 
FROM registrobiblioteca.bajas B 
where B.matricula = a.idAlumno);
```

El nombre de mi base de datos es **registrobiblioteca**

La estructura de mis tablas es esta.

Table: alumno
Columns:
idAlumno int(11) PK
nombre varchar(100)
Grado int(11)
Grupo varchar(45)
ProgramaEducativo varchar(100)

Table: bajas
Columns:
idBajas int(11) AI PK
Matricula int(11)

Edit:
La tabla **idAlumno** contiene las **matrículas** de los alumnos que estén dados de alta en el sistema, mientras que la tabla **bajas** solo guarda el datos de las **matriculas** por motivos administrativos. Solo quiero que los alumnos dados de alta aparezcan en la tabla de **alumnos**.

Comment: Coloca el mensaje de error completo por favor

Comment: ¿Podrias explicarnos qué quieres decir con *Quiero eliminar múltiples datos*? ¿Qué datos, en qué tablas y según qué criterios?

Comment: Ya lo edite pero aun asi lo comento, la tabla idAlumno contiene la matrícula de los alumnos que estén dados de alta en el sistema, mientras que la tabla bajas solo guarda el dato por motivos administrativos. Solo quiero que los alumnos dados de alta aparezcan en la tabla de alumnos.

Answer (score -1):

bueno fijate bien la estructura de la query.

1.Tu error es que despues de delete no va el nombre de la columna sino el de la tabla o bien podes omitir esa parte de la query como en el siguiente ejemplo.

2.asegurate que la relacion entre matricula y idAlumno sea correcta teniendo los mismos valores.

3. otra opcion es hacer un left join. en el caso de left join si necesitas usar delete [nombre de tabla] from [nombre de tabla] left join matricula....

DELETE [NOMBRE DE TABLA]...ETC

segui este ejemplo

```
DELETE FROM suppliers
WHERE EXISTS
  ( SELECT *
    FROM customers
    WHERE customers.customer_id = suppliers.supplier_id
    AND customer_id > 500 );
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar por qué tu código resuelve el problema? Además en la consulta que muestras se usan otras tablas y otros criterios WHERE ... ¿?

Comment: Las respuestas deberían servir para que OP y  futuros usuarios con una situación parecida entiendan por qué el código era erróneo y por qué lo indicado en la respuesta resuelve el error. No hay nada de eso explicado en tu respuesta.

Comment: ahi explique mas lo que puede hacer :)